# How to fix this "object is not subscriptable" TypeError?

Tags: python, object, oop

I am a bit new to python but currently am in a course and there's this type error
Here's the code, I'm basically making a quiz with just true/false answers.

```
question_data = [
 {"text": "A slug's blood is green.", "answer": "True"},

 {"text": "The loudest animal is the African Elephant.", "answer": "False"},

 {"text": "Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.", "answer": "True"},

 {"text": "The total surface area of a human lungs is the size of a football pitch.", "answer": "True"},

 {"text": "In West Virginia, USA, if you accidentally hit an animal with your car, you are free to take it home to eat.", "answer": "True"},

 {"text": "In London, UK, if you happen to die in the House of Parliament, you are entitled to a state funeral.", "answer": "False"},

 {"text": "It is illegal to pee in the Ocean in Portugal.", "answer": "True"},

 {"text": "You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.", "answer": "False"},

 {"text": "Google was originally called 'Backrub'.", "answer": "True"},

 {"text": "Buzz Aldrin's mother's maiden name was 'Moon'.", "answer": "True"},

 {"text": "No piece of square dry paper can be folded in half more than 7 times.", "answer": "False"},

 {"text": "A few ounces of chocolate can to kill a small dog.", "answer": "True"


class Question:

 def __init__(self, q_text, q_answer):
     self.text = q_text
     self.answer = q_answer

#quizbrain function to give the input and retrieve a question from the data
class QuizBrain:
 def __init__(self, q_list):
     self.question_number = 0
     self.question_list = q_list


 def next_question(self):
     current_question = self.question_list[self.question_number]
     self.question_number += 1
     input(f"Q.{self.question_number}: {current_question.text} (True/False):  ")



question_bank = (question_data)
for question in question_data:
 question_text = question["text"]
 question_answer = question["answer"]
 new_question = Question(question_text, question_answer)
 question_bank.append(new_question)

quiz = QuizBrain(question_bank)
quiz.next_question
```

Then there's this type error:
question_text = question["text"]
TypeError: 'Question' object is not subscriptable
any help on this?

Comment: You can search for the error message to locate hundreds of similar questions. You could also extract a [mcve] from your code. That said, please indent with four spaces if you ever want other people to read your Python code. For your question, it lacks the info on which line exactly the error happens. As a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] and show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message. We don't need to see dozens of questions in order to understand the code. We **do** need to see a definition for `question_data` *that is syntactically correct*. We also don't need to see the `QuizBrain` class or anything trying to use it, for example, because all of that happens only after the error you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by this line:

```py
question_bank = (question_data)
```

which is causing you to append your `Question` objects to `question_data` as you go through the list (because it creates `question_bank` as a reference to `question_data` that you then append to).

I don't know why you're actually doing that; I think you actually just want

```py
question_bank = []
```

Making that change (and fixing `quiz.next_question` to `quiz.next_question()`) seems to make your code work (at least as far as it is written so far)

Comment: to be fair I'm just following the course and the way the tutor writes it works for her, no idea how it doesn't work for mine.

Comment: @ArmandSurbakti that's fair enough, but the code cannot work as it is (as you have seen).

Comment: Was there perhaps originally a function defined and called there e.g. `question_bank = makeBank(question_data)`?